# What role did the United States government and major corporations have in controlling dissent and protest starting in the late 1940s?

Tags: united-states, political-history, social-history, cultural-history

After the Second World War, numerous movements of dissent and protest amongst workers or soldiers which had been kept in check by the profits of war developed into significant movements, such as the Coal or Rail strikes in 1946.  Similarly, the war-time consensus on the United States and "Russia" as allies broke down.  What studies of the personal experience of repression in this era—specifically the late 1940s—exist?  What cultural and social histories of the climate of immediate post-war repression exist?

What was it like to live outside of the newly forming post-war consensus in the late 1940s in the United States?

[image: Cartoon]:

Image: Fitzpatrick, Daniel Robert, 1891-1969. 1947: ?St. Louis Post Dispatch

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What do _you_ think?

Comment: This question seems kind of like a [Rorschach test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test) for a person's understanding of the USA and its history. I'm sure that makes it an awesome essay question from a History instructor's point of view, but that same property makes not such a good History.SE question.

Comment: Turned the sentiment into an answerable question

Comment: @SamuelRussell - it's QUITE possible that the cartoonist was actually referring to "a little revolution now and then..." and other similar sentiments by many Founding Fathers, as opposed to 1940s contemporary sentiments.

Comment: @DVK yes, and, in the context of the 1940s, after the repatriation protests were dealt with, the issue of whose blood should be shed did remarkably centre on the issue of control of the Trade Union movement.  The image's context of 1947 the subversives on the table were in the AFL and CIO.  So while Fitzpatrick is almost certainly referencing that American idiom, the context is the post-war settlement over labour.

Comment: I answered for the 1950s (since I was born then). For more information on this topic, I recommend the book "Generations" by William Strauss and Neil Howe.

Answer (score 0):

I was born in the 1950s, so I will answer this question based on my knowledge of the 1950s. The "post war consensus" lasted through the 1950s (heightened by "Sputnik"), and into the 1960s (when the U.S. finally surpassed the Soviet Union in the space race).

One instrument used to accomplish this end was "McCarthyism." That is, labelling "dissidents" as socialists or "Communists."

One example of this was the Senatorial campaign of Richard M. Nixon against Helen Gahagan Douglas. Although wealthy, Douglas was suspected as a "leftist" because she was in "show business." Nixon called Douglas the "Pink Lady," and Douglas in turn called Nixon, "Tricky Dick." (Both nicknames stuck.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Gahagan_Douglas

Nixon's campaign was funded by corporations such as Unocal, then led by Reese Taylor. His successful Senatorial campaign led to his nomination and election as Vice-President in 1952.

Ironically, the American public elected Nixon President in 1968 for his "ability." (He opened the door to China.) Then they turned on him by impeaching him for the Watergate scandal, which at heart, was an attempt to "suppress" Democratic "dissidents."

Comment: The chief problem with this answer is that McCarthy's actions turned on 1949—on the development of a non-US bomb.  This answer would be adequate for a question regarding dissent in the _1950s_.

Comment: @SamuelRussell:  
I put in a disclaimer to say that I was answering for the 1950s (since I was born then), to let the OP decide whether or not the answer is "adequate."

Comment: apologies, I missed your arguing your answer's position in the question ("The "post war consensus" lasted through the 1950s… and into the 1960s"), which I think that answerers should do when they feel the question itself is limited.  Thanks for drawing my attention to that.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: I made the "postwar consensus" correction AFTER reading your critique. Thanks for withdrawing the downvote (if that's what happened).

Comment: I very rarely downvote answers, and didn't this time.  The process of refining an answer until it is complete is valid; your response was always responding to the post-war consensus issue even it it wasn't clearly voiced!